# How to turn a .txt document to all capitalized letters?

Tags: coding-style

We have a coding convention with an obscure, proprietary language called PowerOn (think of a scripty PL/1 language) that **requires all coding text to be capitalized**.  Going behind some previous developers,  people thought they would **carry over their camel case habits** from other languages like Java.  Are there any tools that would transform all text to capitalize all text?

Worst case scenario, I could make somehing in .Net that could accomplish this.  I am just trying to avoid reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Not sure wether to take that as an isult or pitty... Either way has me worried if I am being directed to Experts-Exchage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tr "[a-z]" "[A-Z]" <code.poweron >newcode.poweron
```

Comment: Note that this would also capitalise all string literals which might not be what the OP wants.

Comment: +1 for being very succinct.  A windows tool would be nice as well.

Comment: @hydroparadise You could use cygwin, which brings a lot of the command line linux tools to windows

Comment: @HristoIliev Nice to point out, I just happen to be lucky that a many of these don't have very many string literals, so this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

In case you're on linux you have a number of options. Two of these are:

```
1. dd if=input.txt of=output.txt conv=ucase
2. tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' < input.txt > output.txt
```